# ¿Cómo puedo reducir el código siguiente en PHP?

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo reducir el código siguiente?

```
$gestionComentario         = ($_POST['txta_comentario']);

$gestionComentarioEspacios = str_replace("    ", "", $gestionComentario);
$gestionComentarioTab      = str_replace("\n", "", $gestionComentarioEspacios);
$gestionComentarioComa     = str_replace(",", "", $gestionComentarioTab);
$gestionComentarioPunto    = str_replace(".", "", $gestionComentarioComa);

$gestionComentarioBr       = str_replace("\r", "", $gestionComentarioPunto);
```

Recibo una cadena de texto por POST en la variable $gestionComentario, posteriormente lo paso por 5 veces la funcion "str_replace();" de PHP en donde replazo 4 espacio, fines de linea, comas, puntos, retorno de carro, para que al final quede mi cadena de texto sin todo eso en la variable $gestionComentarioBr, ¿Hay alguna manera de reducir todas esas lineas de codigo sin perjudicar quitar todo eso antes mencionado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un array con todos los reemplazos que necesitas y pasarlos como primer parámetro a `str_replace`, por ejemplo:

```
$toReplace=array("    ", "\n", ",", ".", "\r");
$gestionComentario         = ($_POST['txta_comentario']);
$mData=str_replace($toReplace,"",$gestionComentario);

#Test
var_dump($mData);
```

Si quisieras una reemplazo más avanzado (parecido a una traducción o reemplazo de marcadores), podrías usar [`strtr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtr.php), útil cuando quieres reemplazar por más de un valor.

Por ejemplo:

```
$mParams=array("oldA"=>"newA", "oldB"=>"newB");
$newString=strtr($originalString,$mParams);
```

Esto te cambiaría `oldA` por `newA` y `oldB` por `newB` en `$originalString`.

Answer (score 4):

Hola puede usar `preg_replace` para remover con el uso de una `regex`

```
$string = "String con \n algunos caracteres . que , no son \r válidos";
$pattern = '/[\s\n\r.,]/i';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

puede usar la expreción regular que desee
Saludos

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarme cómo funciona lo que se coloca dentro del arreglo []? Entiendo que \ es por default del valor que quiero remplazar pero... ¿Por qué la , no tiene ese slash inverso y el . si?

Comment: Para esta variante utilizamos expreciones regulares (cuando tenga un tiempo estudie sobre ellas le va a ser muy útil), dento de los `[]` lo que hago es poner la expreción que quiero comprobar en en esta caso son los caracteres de espacio(\s), salto de línea (\n), retorno (\r), punto y la coma, pero se pueden crear infinitas expreciones, se me fue el `.` no llevaba el \ ya edité la respuesta